# react query useinifinite query returns previous data on handlescroll am i implementing it wrong?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query

my backend receives the get request in /?pages={number},im trying to implement infinte scroll in react native using react query to get data and pass it through the flatlist

the issue is that the onreachend the data appended is the previous data from /?pages={0]

```
useInfiniteQuery({
          queryKey: ["reports"],
          getNextPageParam: (prevData, allData) => {
            // console.log(allData.length);
            // console.log("has next page ", hasNextPage);
            return prevData.length < 10 ? false : allData.length - 1;
          },
          queryFn: ({ pageParam = 0 }) => {
            // console.log("page params", pageParam);
            return GetUserReports(pageParam);
          },
        });
    
      const HandleScroll = () => {
        if (!fetching) {
          if (hasNextPage === true) {
            console.log(data.pages.map((page) => page).flat().length);
            return fetchNextPage();
          }
        }
      };
```

here is the flatlist where the data is called

```
<FlatList
              initialNumToRender={3}
              showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
              estimatedItemSize={3}
              data={data.pages.map((page) => page).flat() || []}
              removeClippedSubviews={true}
              windowSize={5}
              onEndReached={HandleScroll}
              onEndReachedThreshold={1}
              renderItem={(item) => {
                return (
                  <Report
                    report={item}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM solved it

```
  getNextPageParam: (prevData, allData) => {
    // console.log(allData.length);
    // console.log("has next page ", hasNextPage);
    return prevData.length < 10 ? false : allData.length;
  },
```

the code was sending alldata.length-1 , in that case a length of 1 would fetch the previously fetched data